# Habra una forma de poder visualizar solo los aeropuertos con mayor movimiento?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

En este ejercicio se solicita que muestre el nombre del aeropuerto que tienen mas movimientos con los datos de la tabla

[image: Datos tabla vuelo]

con un Query se requiere llegar a esa información el que tengo me da el listado de todos los aeropuertos y necesito que me muestre solo el que tiene el maximo de movimientos.

eso lo conseguí con este query:

```
select 
A.nombre_aeropuerto as Aeropuerto, count(V.id_movimiento) Numero_de_movimientos 
from vuelos V 
join aeropuertos A on V.id_aeropuerto=A.id_aeropuerto
join movimientos M on V.id_movimiento=M.id_movimiento 
group by A.nombre_aeropuerto;
```

Y considero que mis tablas muy independientemente de los tipos de datos seleccionados estan correctas

[image: Modelo Entidad Relación]

Espero alguien me pueda dar luz al respecto, de antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Cual es el problema?

Comment: Gracias por compartirnos los detalles de tablas y la consulta que estás probando... por favor ve a [edit] y cuéntanos cuál es el problema aquí :)

Answer (score 0):

Además de tener en cuenta las indicaciones que te han escrito en los comentarios. Por favor, comprueba si el resultado que buscas lo consigues así:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT id_aeropuerto
      FROM vuelos
      GROUP BY 1
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id_movimiento)=(
        SELECT MAX(Numero_de_movimientos) FROM (
            SELECT id_aeropuerto,
              COUNT(DISTINCT id_movimiento) Numero_de_movimientos
              FROM vuelos
              GROUP BY 1  
          ) c1  
      )  
  ) c2 JOIN aeropuertos USING(id_aeropuerto);
```

En ese caso, debes tener en cuenta que los movimientos por aeropuerto no dependen del número de aerolíneas implicadas en cada uno de esos movimientos. Por eso es necesario el `DISTINCT` en el `COUNT()`. En caso contrario, simplemente quítaselo.

A tu consulta, además de ese `DISTINCT`, le faltaría un `ORDER BY Numero_de_movimientos LIMIT 1` para que te diera este mismo resultado. Mi propuesta es un poco más complicada, pero más eficiente porque no requiere realizar ninguna ordenación.

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios para poder ampliar la respuesta.